# How to solve $y' =\dfrac {x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried from the method of solving homogenous method. But, I could not obtain anyhing from there.
$$y' =\dfrac {x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$$

I made a transformation $$y = ux \implies y' = u'x + u$$ ; then I obtained $$u'x = \dfrac {(1-u^2 - u -u^3)}{1+u^2}$$ ... then nothing came from here

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please write also down how far you got, you have identified the method correctly.

Comment: I made a transformation y = ux ---> y' = u'x + u ;
then I obtained u'x = (1-u^2 - u -u^3)/(1+u^2) ... then nothing came from here

Comment: Please use the edit link and add that to the question text. At this point you have a separable equation with rational terms. Do the separation of variables and then the partial fraction decomposition. At least find the qualitative properties of the roots and what terms you can expect after integration.

Comment: Couldnt obtain anything...

Comment: You are on the right track. The equation is separable.